# admod sdk deprecated, use google play services for froyo too

Tags: admob, google-play-services, android-2.2-froyo

I supported froyo 2.2 on my apps and in august I received an
email that apps with the old admob sdk would not be served more
ads after a certain date. The solution was to use the google play services
7.0 or later and I updated my apps, currently using this version on my
build.gradle:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'

The problem is that I can no longer support minSdkversion 8 (froyo).

IS there any alternative way to support both froyo and later versions
even with including google plau services 9.2.1

Thank you.

Comment: add conditional check for version 8 < use ad mediation network . Search for other mediations which supports 2.2. Here is official list from Google https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation-networks

Comment: I think there is no way to use the minSdkversion 8 (froyo) with the Google Play Service 9.2 version. If you try to use it in your project you will got an error and give you a message that you need to use minSdkversion 9. And according to this [link](https://blog.xamarin.com/improvements-to-the-google-play-services-component/), that today version of Google Play Service 8.x.x or 9.x.x are for projects that target Android 4.0 (API level 14) or higher. Also, check the link provided by [Amod Gokhale](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2323607/amod-gokhale), it might help you also about the admob.

Comment: Hello Arnold, by ad mediation network, you mean to use a different network than admob?